# count the words starts with a-z character using dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, counting

> Load the dictionary in python as a list from following url "https://cfstatic.org/static/words.txt". Using this word list, create a python dictionary (or an array if you are using php)
>
> with the following property :
>   key : alphabet [a-z]
>   value: number of words starting with that alphabet in the dictionary

I want the result as

```
a : number of words start with a 
b : number of words start with b  
[...]
z : number of words start with z
```

I have done the following,

```
import urllib2  # the lib that handles the url stuff
try:
    input_file = urllib2.urlopen('https://cfstatic.org/static/words.txt') # it's a file like object and works just like a file
    myNames = []
    for line in input_file:
        myNames.append(line.strip()) #strips the new line in list
    print myNames                      #print the file as list
except urllib2.URLError as e:         #raise the exception if url is not found
    print "Error Message : %s" %e
else:
    print "File reading operation successful!!!"
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please ask a question. This is a question/answer site.

Comment: So, where did you get stuck? Did you try to create a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your for loop to create a dictionary rather than just a list. Something like:-

```
alphabet = {}
for line in input_file:
    line = line.strip()
    starts_with = line[0]
    if line[0] in alphabet:
        alphabet[line[0]].append(line)
    else:
        alphabet[line[0]] = [line]
for key in alphabet:
    alphabet[key] = len(alphabet[key])
```

As one of the other answer suggests, you can also go as(don't need to store the elements):-

```
alphabet = {}
for line in input_file:
    line = line.strip()
    starts_with = line[0]
    if starts_with in alphabet:
        alphabet[starts_with]+= 1
    else:
        alphabet[starts_with] = 1

print alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Counter` from the `collections` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was made for this.

Transform the list-of-words into a list-of-first characters (the `map(...)` call below) and then feed that iterable straight into a `collections.Counter` object:

```
>>> import collections                                                                                                                 
>>> words = ["aap", "noot", "mies", "foo", "appel"]                                                                                    
>>> collections.Counter(map(lambda x: x[0], words))                                                                                    
Counter({'a': 2, 'f': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1})
```

Comment: No need for `map` and `lambda` here - use a gen-exp instead... `collections.Counter(word[0] for word in words)`

Comment: Also fine - anything that gets you an iterable yielding the first letter of each word!

Comment: Indeed... but it's far less expensive than map/lambda and consistent aross 2.x/3.x... In 2.x - map will also build a list which isn't required - just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a list with letters, than iterate through list with words you have, and add them to dictionary or increment counter in dictionary in way as below:

```
letters = [chr(l) for l in range(97,123)]
d = {}
for word in myNames:
    d.update({word[0]: 1}) if not d.has_key(word[0]) else d.update({word[0]: d[word[0]]+1})
```

I hope that would work for you. Write me if you need an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I could think of is this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
output_dict = dict.fromkeys(ascii_lowercase, 0)
input = " this is a text message"
for ch in input:
    if ch in ascii_lowercase:
        output_dict[ch] += 1

for character, count in output_dict.items():
    if count:
        print "%s : count is %s" % (character, count)
```

In case you dont want to use string module or would like to reduce the characters on your own, you can put something like this:

```
alphabets_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
output_dict = dict.fromkeys(alphabets_lower, 0)
```

Have fun :-)